# current time not working in flowplayer (seeking issue)

Tags: flowplayer

```
<a href="javascript:seek(10)" ></a>
```

Please see below link I want to current time+ and current time- functionality

http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html

Comment: ok,if we want functionality similar like in given link...
in flowplayer.js like current time + and current time -

Comment: we are using Flowplayer.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`seek` is a *method* on the flowplayer object, so you need to do something like this:

```
flowplayer($(".myplayer")).seek(10);
```

If you have a flowplayer with the class `myplayer`.

Comment: Hi, its working for fixed time. but i want to change timing when we click on prev and next that time duration is increase plus 10

Comment: can we you seeked ? and before seek ?

Comment: @kruti: use ``flowplayer($(".myplayer")).seek( flowplayer($(".myplayer")).getTime() + 10)``.

Comment: Sorry, This code is not working its getting error "object has no method"
I will use this code 
var playerapi = flowplayer($(".flowplayer"));
var current_time = playerapi.ready ? playerapi.video.time : 0;
var final_time = current_time + 10 ;
flowplayer($(".flowplayer")).seek(final_time);
working for me and i got solution
Thanks for help